# NAS device for distributed team

Tags: vpn, network-share, network-attached-storage

We are a distributed team spread across 5 locations. We have a shared drive (1 TB data) at our former location that we are currently accessing via Hamachi VPN. Our shared drive is a network folder on a Windows Server located at one of our locations.

The current connection speed is terrible. The upload speed at the current location of the shared drive is very slow. We looking for a NAS device that we can host at another location with better upload speed that all of us can access.

I am looking for a NAS device that has these features:

1. Minimal Maintenance as we do not have dedicated IT resources
2. Access data on the device from multiple locations.
3. Ability to create network drive (On Windows Computers >> Map Network Drive)
4. Upload data from random client computers without having to install software. (Right now, we use LogMeIn Rescue's file manager)
5. Ability handle slow or dropped connections when transferring files (Maximum size 1.5 GB)

Answer (score 3):

I think using a cloud service (Box, others) makes a lot of sense for your requirements, especially "minimal maintenance," , and "multiple locations."

$15/user/month for Box, with some nice (AD integration, version history, central admin) features.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're basically asking for cloud storage.  Box is an option, but I'd say pick your poison (Google Drive, Dropbox, Microsoft's OneDrive) in terms of your feature requirements I think any of the big players would suit your needs.

On your point number 4 - I was constantly looking for a way to send files to my Dropbox from client PCs where I didn't want to login to my account.  I had an [Airdropper](https://airdropper.com) account for a while but its $9/month.  I recently switched to [DBinbox](http://dbinbox.com/).  It's a lot more barebones but its free and gets the job done.